# Using Time Capsule with existing Sky ADSL router

Tags: network, wifi, time-capsule

We've got a Sky ADSL router which we have running a wifi network, and we've got it connected via ethernet to iMac/TV/PS3/etc. As the wifi coverage isn't great upstairs we've bought a Time Capsule which we want to plug in to the ethernet that's connected to the router, and we want to have the Time Capsule provide wifi coverage upstairs.

I've only been able to make this work by having the Time Capsule create a separate wifi network, with its own name & password, which means when you go upstairs you have to manually change networks. What we really want is a single network, but when I try changing the Wireless settings to 'Extend a wireless network' I just can't get it to work -- I end up with the TC flashing its light amber.

Surely this must be possible? Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the same question on the Apple forums, and got a solution that worked for me:

https://discussions.apple.com/message/20182532?ac_cid=op123456#20182532

I'll repeat it here so somebody else might find it useful in the future:

This is where you use a roaming network.

Do not extend.. that is much slower.. since you have ethernet and the TC plugged in you are 90% of the way there.

Use the TC to create a network.. with the same name and same passkey with security settings as the wireless downstairs. Locking channels is not a bad idea.. as this does require one difference .. the network upstairs must be on a different channel to the one downstairs.. then all will be hunky dorey.. !!

Comment: +1 for this. And get yourself a copy of Wifi Scanner, which will distinguish the different sources of an identical SSID and show you what the channel traffic in your neighborhood looks like -- invaluable for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

In general, making an Airport extend another network is painful unless the vendor of that device explicitly supports and encourages it.

Apple's devices seem to do much better extending their own networks, so I would encourage you to simply let the Airport run the entire network (or a parallel network while operating in bridge mode) to let the clients select whichever Wi-Fi is best at the moment in their specific locations.